# redoing object model construction to fit with asynchronous data fetching

Tags: .net, silverlight, oop, asynchronous, class-design

I have a modeled a set of objects that correspond with some real world
concepts.

TradeDrug, GenericDrug, TradePackage, DrugForm

Underlying the simple object model I am trying to provide is a complex
medical terminology that uses numeric codes to represent relationships
and concepts, all accessible via a REST service - I am trying to 
hide away some of that complexity with an object wrapper.

To give a concrete example

I can call

```
TradeDrug d = Searcher.FindTradeDrug("Zoloft")    or
TradeDrug d = new TradeDrug(34)
```

where 34 might be the code for Zoloft. This will consult a remote
server to find out some details about Zoloft. I might then call

```
GenericDrug generic = d.EquivalentGeneric()
System.Out.WriteLine(generic.ActiveIngredient().Name)
```

in order to get back the generic drug sertraline as an object (again via a
background REST call to the remote server that has all these drug
details), and then perhaps find its ingredient.

This model works fine and is being used in some applications
that involve data processing.

Recently however I wanted to do
a silverlight application that used and displayed these
objects. The silverlight environment only allows asynchronous
REST/web service calls. I have no problems with how to make the
asychhronous calls - but I am having trouble with what
the design should be for my object construction.

Currently the constructors for my objects do some
REST calls sychronously.

```
 public TradeDrug(int code)
 {
     form = restclient.FetchForm(code)
     name = restclient.FetchName(code)
     etc..
 }
```

If I have to use async 'events' or 'actions' in order to use
the Silverlight web client (I know silverlight can be
forced to be a synchronous client but I am interested in
asychronous approaches), does anyone have an guidance
or best practice for how to structure my objects.

I can pass in an action callback to the constructor

```
 public TradeDrug(int code, Action<TradeDrug> constructCompleted)
 {

 }
```

but this then allows the user to have a TradeDrug
object instance before what I want to construct
is actually finished. It also doesn't support an
'event' async pattern because the object doesn't exist
to add the event to until it is constructed.

Extending that approach might be a factory object that itself
has an asynchronous interface to objects

```
 factory.GetTradeDrugAsync(code, completedaction)
```

or with a GetTradeDrugCompleted event?

Does anyone have any recommendations? Does anyone know
how the new Reactive framework might fit in with any
solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would ditch the public constructors and go with async factory methods. It need not be a separate factory object, it could just be static methods on TradeDrug itself, something like:

```
public static void LoadByIdAsync(int id) { ... }
public static void LoadByIdAsync(int id, object userState) { ... }
public static event LoadByIdCompletedEventHandler LoadByIdCompleted;
```

The event-based async pattern is described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wewwczdw.aspx

Comment: thanks Alex. For bonus credit, I'm also interested in how the object construction patterns might best fit in with the new Reactive framework. My understanding is that the 'event' path might be a slightly uncomfortable fit (noting that I know next to nothing about Reactive)